# Service X mounts volumes from Y, which is not the name of a service or container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using docker-compose I'm attempting to create a shared volume that two of my services can both use. I have the following in my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  bundler:
    driver: local
sidekiq:
  build: .
  volumes_from:
    - bundler:/.bundle
web:
  build: .
  volumes_from:
    - bundler:/.bundle
```

This however doesn't work and gives me:

> ERROR: Service "sidekiq" mounts volumes from "bundler", which is not the name of a service or container.

What is the correct way of doing this using docker-compose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mixed two concepts here.

- `volumes_from` is used when one container has some volumes (mounted or not) that should be used for storage. You can then use this container's volumes by referencing the so called `data-only-container` with `volumes_from` which must point to a container or (compose) service name.
- `volumes` on the other hand is used to reference either a local folder or a named volume. A named volume then must be declared in the top level entry `volumes` of the compose file as you already did.

So in your case, a switch from `volumes_from` to `volumes` should do the trick. Please see the reference docs for details: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/volumes-volume-driver

Comment: this is a perfect and detailed explanation and the theory behind my suggestion for the answer above. We should have combined both for a good answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  bundler:
    driver: local
sidekiq:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - bundler:/.bundle
web:
  build: .
  volumes_from:
    - sidekiq:rw
```

So sidekiq is you so called `data-container`, exposing and creating the `bundler` volume. Then you mount this volume in all other containers you need it, in your case for now web. Hope this helps

Comment: sidekiq isn't really the traditional definition of a data-container since it's mounting it's data from a named volume. Since your data is in a named volume, adding the extra dependency on sidekiq to be running is adding an unnecessary dependency between the two services. In other words, with this design, you can't upgrade sidekiq without destroying and later recreating the web container.

Comment: Intersting point. Web is mounting using the containter syntax, not the volume syntax, thus its dependency goes to the container. If i stop all containers, then i should be able to remove sidekiq / upgrade sidekiq, right(?) Beside that, upgrading sidekiq would not make sense in practical righti, since its a `cogniteev/echo` anyway, right? Do you mind explaining your thoughts more detailed?

Comment: If you stop all containers, you can upgrade sidekiq. But if you use a named volume instead of a container volume, you can upgrade sidekiq without needing to stop web (see the answer I posted for how to do that). That decouples the dependencies between each container and makes them independently upgradeable. They each still have identical access to the data.

Comment: i tried that - and you do not need to stop web when you want to upgrade sidekiq. You stop sidekiq, rm it, upgrade it and start it again, reusing the same volume. Web does not need to be stopped during

Comment: Now try stopping them both and restarting just the web container. You'll find that it forces you to start the sidekiq container.

Comment: very interesting. To not drag this comments into a full fledged discussion, i invite you to discuss this issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013222/data-container-with-names-volumes-conceptual-problems - very tensed to see what cases we can work out

Answer (score 0):

The "volumes_from" references a container. Since you're using a named volume, you need "volumes":

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  bundler:
    driver: local
services:
  sidekiq:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - bundler:/.bundle
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - bundler:/.bundle
```

Also, since you're using version 2, you need to specify services in their own `services:` section instead of the top level of the yml.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use **volumes_from** with a container(data only), use

```
volumes_from:
 - container:"yourdataonlycontainer"
```