# `data-container` with named or anonymous volumes - conceptual problems? (Discussion)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

### a) Anonymous volumes

When using data-containers, you can either use anonymous volumes like this

```
version '2'
services:
  consumer:
    volume_from:
      - data-container:rw
  data-container:
    image: cogniteev/echo
    command: echo 'Data Container'
    volume:
      - /var/www
```

### b) Name volumes

or you can use named volumes like this

```
version '2'
services:
  consumer:
    volume_from:
      - data-container:rw
  data-container:
    image: cogniteev/echo
    command: echo 'Data Container'
    volume:
      - my-named-volume:/var/www

 volumes:
   my-named-volume:
     driver: local
```

I usually go with b) and would like to discuss / get explained the conceptual issues / flaws of maybe both of those. So what are the pros and cons.

The aspects we can compare them against are / could be:

1. portability
2. upgradeability of the data-container (why would we ever upgrade the container ? )
3. Start/Stop (continue) compatibility?
4. multiple-stack issues?
5. efficiency ( reuse of the volume )

This question spwaned du to the discussion on this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/38984689/3625317

Comment: Named volumes were created to replace data containers. I don't know of any use cases where data containers are preferred. See [this similar (dup?) question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36011595/596285)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: named data volumes are preferred, data containers are no longer needed, so you should never use `volumes-from` on any new project.

Your version of named volumes is merging a named and data container, it should be:

```
version '2'
services:
  web:
    image: my-web-image
    volumes:
      - my-named-volume:/var/www

 volumes:
   my-named-volume:
     driver: local
```

By merging the two, you've added an extra layer of indirection to reach your named volume, without any added benefits. Named volumes were created in 1.9 to [replace data containers](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17798) which were themselves a somewhat hacked method to provide persistent data. Advantages of named volumes over data containers include:

- Your data management is separate from your container management, you can remove all running containers and still have your data available
- Data can be stored in different locations using volume drivers, which means you can put it on nfs, a distributed file system, or even a local persistent directory
- You may start and stop any container in any order without dependencies between containers
- When first created, a named volume will receive a copy of the image filesystem it is first mounted on top of, identical to the behavior of data containers, which means it's a seamless transition (note that this is not the behavior of a host volume, aka bind mount)

See also [this question that also discusses named volumes vs data containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36011595/596285) and [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/760244/351549) to another similar question. We also have a [blog post on this](https://boxboat.com/2016/06/18/docker-data-containers-and-named-volumes/) by a company that I work for.

Comment: thank you very much, sir. Those are really valuable informations, esp. that it is actually intended to replace data-containers since 1.9.

Comment: For further reference, also the docs got updated to remove the mention that data-containers are best-practice https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20465 - so this all seconds your answer

Comment: They need to be updated still, that issue is open. Might be time for me to check out the code and make a pull request.

Comment: Yes, you are right, https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container is still present and not yet updated .. created a comment https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20465#issuecomment-240756653 but i guess, that will not help the progress. Seeing how much confusion this topic spreads, a best-practice guide should be really something to strive for